# Add additional package when installing Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, lubuntu

I want to install Lubuntu 18.04 using a live usb stick. I don't have a internet connection during the installation (actually, I'm behind a http proxy). After the installation, I want to immidiatly run an ansible script for configuration management. The problem is: The default installation does not install openssh-server.

How can I add the package openssh-server to my installation media and automatically install it during the installation process?

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu Server does include openssh-server.

Comment: Yes I know. If I want to go that path the question would be what's the exact differences between ubuntu server (with apt install lubuntu-desktop) and lubuntu in regard to configuration (e.g. ubuntu server does obviously not boot lxde by default)?